# ADODB Recordset return Null values for hidden columns in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

I'm trying to retrieve data from an Excel worksheet using ADODB.connection and .recordset objects. Generally, the whole procedure works without any errors, however, when a column/field in the source excel is hidden, the recordset query produce only "Null" values for that specific hidden column.

The hidden column is apparently visible by the connection/recordset because there is no SQL error due to unrecognized field and I can even get rs.Field(i).Name value of this hidden column. But somehow ADO is not able to get the values of hidden columns.

The Null values are returned when using rs.copyfromrecordset method, looping through all records for each field, or checking in the immediate window.

I do not see any properties of the connection/recordset that would handle this situation. Is that a limitation/bug of the ADO?

**Edit.**

For the ConnectionString, I use standard ACE Provider with Read mode and Properties Excel XML or Excel Macro.

```
cn.ConnectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Mode='Read';" & _
    "Data Source=" & fullFilePath & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
cn.Open
```

For the recordset, I use following setting.

```
With rs
    .ActiveConnection = cn
    .CursonType = adOpenStatic
    .Source = SQL_Query
    .Open
End with
```

Would appreciate any help on that. Thanks!

Comment: Pleases share the code in your post. I have tested it (`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`) w/o any issues on Excel 365.

Comment: @taller I have edited my Question to include the  code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Please test it w/ a simple sql `sql = "select * from [sheet1$a:f]"`. Assumes there is a hidden col in A:F.

Comment: It returned all values for visible columns and Null values for hidden columns (empty columns). The number of Columns/Fields returned was equal to number of columns in range [sheet1$range]

Comment: The value should be Null if the column is empty / blank. It is not related with hidden. What's your expected result?

Comment: I wouldn't ask a question if the hidden columns in the source file were blank, obviously :)  they have values but the returned fields/columns in the recordset are blank.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on my pc.

Comment: I tried some simple examples on my own PC and also can't reproduce the problem. It's good news, but I have no idea what is the issue with the file I was working on at work. Will have a second look at this later. Thanks @taller for your help on that.

Comment: Possibly that problem column has values with mixed types (numbers/text/date)? That can lead to ADO returning nulls instead of the values in the column.

Comment: ...or the first x rows are blank, which I seem to recall can have the same effect.

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for your suggestion. The problem indeed was the values in the affected columns. For some reason, the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB provider interpreted the column as "Date" type and all the values which were not formatted in the "date" format were erased. Funny is that, the column did not contain any date values in any of the cells so I am not sure why the column was interpreted that way.

The solution for me was to insert " ' " in the first row cell so that the driver interpreted the column as Text type.

Comment: Please do not edit your question with *(Solved)*. Instead, answer your own question and accept it (checkmark on side) to confirm resolution of post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the values in the affected columns, as suggested by Tim. For some reason, the Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB provider interpreted the column as "Date" type and all the values which were not formatted in the "date" format were erased (in my understanding). The column did not contain any date values in any of the cells so it's still unclear why the column type was interpretted that way. The solution for me was to insert " ' " in the first row cell so that the column was recognized as Text type.

Comment: Ideally I would format the answer better to show the code snippets